# postGIS+NASAworldwind+library import issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gis

I am trying to import gov.nasa libraries to a postGIS code in IntelliJ IDE.I am aware of the libraries and I know I am writing them correctly although when entered in the header of the code, the IDE says the package does not exist.

### I am adding an example code too for further reference.

```
package gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples;

import gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWind;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.avlist.*;
import gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.util.RandomShapeAttributes;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.exception.WWRuntimeException;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.formats.geojson.*;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Position;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.*;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.render.*;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.util.*;


import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloNasaWorldWind extends JFrame
{
    WorldWindowGLCanvas world;
    public HelloNasaWorldWind()
    {
        world = new WorldWindowGLCanvas();
        world.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 800));
        this.getContentPane().add(world, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        world.setModel(new BasicModel());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new HelloNasaWorldWind();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setName("My first Application");
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you navigate to the class (Navigate | Class action)? Can you build the project? Make sure the library jar is listed in [Dependencies tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies-tab.html) of the module with the **compile** scope. Try also File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.. | Invalidate and Restart action.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yole, it is working now.